# socket.io emit to one client not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io 1.7.3 version. Server code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id); // CdnNBVe9ktJmMcb1AAAA
  socket.to(socket.id).emit('something');
  socket.emit('something'); // if I do it without to, it works but to all clients
  console.log(socket.rooms); // { CdnNBVe9ktJmMcb1AAAA 'CdnNBVe9ktJmMcb1AAAA' }
});
```

Client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect(..);
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(socket.id); // CdnNBVe9ktJmMcb1AAAA
    socket.on('something', function() {
        alert('it works');
    });
});
```

Why it doesn't work? I'm not getting any alert although all console.logs seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message to the particular client, you must provide socket.id of that client to the server and at the server side socket.io takes care of delivering that message by using,

```
 socket.broadcast.to('ID').emit( 'send msg', {somedata : somedata_server} );
```

In your code

```
 socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('something');
```

Comment: neither doesn't work for me, but anyway in docs I can see this: socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');